# Class is Private and members are Public what its scope?

Tags: c#

If class declare as a **Private** and its Members are **Public** so what is the accessibility of related class?

Comment: Read this => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers

Comment: To answer your specific question - a `private class` is `private` - regardless of the visibility of its members.

Comment: This does feel a bit like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Can you talk us through why you are asking the question?

Comment: Classes don't have "scope" (scope in C# is defined for variables)... Classes and methods have "accessibility" (defined by `private`/`public` modifiers). Could you please update your post with proper terminology and clarify what "related class" you are talking about (sounds like some other type)? Small code sample would greatly help.

Comment: If a public person enters a private club, is that person still availiable to the people outside the club?

Answer (score 1):

If your private class implements some interface you can access to public methods via the interface. Here's piece of code:

```
public interface ITest
{
    void Test();    
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ITest nestedProgram = new NestedProgram();
        AnyOtherClass otherClass = new AnyOtherClass();
        otherClass.AnyMethod(nestedProgram);
    }

    private class NestedProgram : ITest
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test method invoked");
        }
    }
}

public class AnyOtherClass
{
    // won't compile
    // public void AnyMethod(Program.NestedProgram test)
    public void AnyMethod(ITest test)
    {
        // won't compile
        //ITest nestedProgram = new Program.NestedProgram();
        test.Test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Access modifiers are keywords used to specify the declared accessibility of a member or a type.

public modifier

The public keyword is an access modifier for types and type members. Public access is the most permissive access level.

There are no restrictions on accessing public members.

Accessibility

> Can be accessed by objects of the class
>
> Can be accessed by derived classes

Private access is the least permissive access level.

Private members are accessible only within the body of the class or the struct in which they are declared.

Accessibility

> Cannot be accessed by object.
>
> Cannot be accessed by derived classes.

Now lets come to the exact answer if the class is declared as private and its members are public then accessibility level of members will stay within class because private class can't be inherited.

Comment: The OP specifically asked for the *combination* of private class and public method

Answer (score 0):

The class is what you declare it as. The "private" modifier on the class declaration matters on nested classes, but there's nothing to stop the class its nested in using its public members. I would argue that the two aren't particularly related because their goals are slightly different (one is the visibility of the class itself for instantiation and where it can be referenced, the other controls what members can be accessed).

Also consider this example:

```
public interface ITest
{
    void TestMethod();
}

public static class TestFactory
{
    private class Test: ITest
    {
        public void TestMethod() { }
    }

    public static ITest CreateTest()
    {
        return new Test();
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
TestFactory.Test a = new TestFactory.Test(); // doesn't work because the class is private
TestFactory.Test b = null; // also doesn't work because the class is private
ITest c = null; // works, the interface is public
ITest d = TestFactory.CreateTest(); // works, because the interface is public and CreateTest is declared to return the interface.
```

In this example, only `TestFactory` can see the class to create an instance of it. On the other hand, the return value is the public interface, which states that implementers should have a public method TestMethod();

In this situation, the method has to be public. Although only TestFactory can directly instantiate and see the class, it can still be exposed through an interface (or base class).

Anyway, it's probably best to take a look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers).